# Read lines with spaces in a txt file

Tags: c

```
typedef struct
{
    char foodCategory[15],foodName1[30],foodName2[30],foodName3[30];
    double foodPrice1,foodPrice2,foodPrice3;
}Food;

void print_food()
{
    Food c[300];
    int lineNumber = 2,index = 1;
  
    FILE *file = fopen("Food.txt","r");

    if (file != NULL)
    {
        char line[300];
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL)
        {
            if (index == lineNumber)
            {
                sscanf(line,"%14s-%29s %lf %29s %lf %29s %lf",
                       c[lineNumber].foodCategory,
                       c[lineNumber].foodName1,
                       c[lineNumber].foodPrice1,
                       c[lineNumber].foodName2,
                       c[lineNumber].foodPrice2,
                       c[lineNumber].foodName3,
                       c[lineNumber].foodPrice3);
                printf("---%s---\n",c[lineNumber].foodCategory);
                printf("%s\t%lf\n", c[lineNumber].foodName1,c[lineNumber].foodPrice1);
                printf("%s\t%lf\n", c[lineNumber].foodName2,c[lineNumber].foodPrice2);
                printf("%s\t%lf\n", c[lineNumber].foodName3,c[lineNumber].foodPrice3);
            }
            else
            {
                index++;
            }
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No file found");
    }
}
```

So the code above is a function that prints a list of foods and their prices from a text file. What will be printed will be based on the user for example if `lineNumber=1` then the line at "Side Dishes" will be printed, if `lineNumber=2` then the line at "Main Course" will be printed and so on.
This is what the inside of the "Food.txt" file looks like:

```
Side Dishes-French fries 69.00 Buffalo wings 99.00 Creamy soup 60.00 
Main Course-Beef Wellington 210.00 Tuna Penne 189.00 Braised Ribs 210.00 
Desserts-Carrot cake 79.00 Strawberry Cheesecake 79.00 Strawberry Shortcake 79.00
Drinks-Cold Lemon 75.00 Cucumber Juice 59.00 Iced Coffee 50.00
```

And this is what I wanted the output to look like when `lineNumber=2`:

```
---Main Course---
Beef Wellington    210.00 
Tuna Penne         189.00
Braised Ribs       210.00
```

Instead it showed up like this:

```
---Main---
    0.000000        0.000000          0.000000---Desserts-Carrot---
    0.000000        0.000000          0.000000---Drinks-Cold---
    0.000000        0.000000          0.000000
```

I think this has something do with how I formatted the `sscanf` but I'm lost. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should break the loop when you've found the line you are interested in. No need to look in following lines.

Comment: Did you successfully compiled your code without warnings? The price variables must be pointer type in sscanf.

Comment: sscanf will stop on the first space when reading a string. So when you think reading "Main Course", you only get "Main".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. Basically, I replaced `sscanf` by some string manipulation to parse the lines.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct
{
    char foodCategory[15], foodName1[30], foodName2[30], foodName3[30];
    double foodPrice1, foodPrice2, foodPrice3;
} Food;

char* getFoodItem(char* p, char* foodName, int sizeoffoodName, double* foodPrice)
{
    *foodName  = 0;
    *foodPrice = 0;
    if ((p == NULL) || (*p == 0))
        return p;
    // Ignore leading spaces
    while (*p == ' ')
        p++;

    // Search next digit or decimal point or end of line
    char* q = p;
    q = strpbrk(q, "0123456789.\r\n");
    if (q == NULL)
        return NULL;
    q[-1] = 0;
    strncpy(foodName, p, sizeoffoodName);
    char price[10];
    char* r = price;
    while (((*q >= '0') && (*q <= '9')) || (*q == '.')) {
        if ((r - price) >= sizeof(price))  // Check buffer overflow
            return NULL;
        *r++ = *q++;
    }
    *r = 0;
    *foodPrice = atof(price);
    return q;
}


void print_food()
{
    Food c[300];
    int lineNumber = 2, index = 1;

    FILE* file = fopen("Food.txt", "r");

    if (file != NULL)
    {
        char line[300];
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL)
        {
            if (index == lineNumber) {
                char* p;
                p = strchr(line, '-');  // Search for hyphen separator
                if (p == NULL) {
                    printf("Missing hyphen\n");
                    return;
                }
                *p++ = 0; // replace hyphen by end of string
                strncpy(c[lineNumber].foodCategory, line, sizeof(c[lineNumber].foodCategory));
                p = getFoodItem(p, c[lineNumber].foodName1, sizeof(c[lineNumber].foodName1), &c[lineNumber].foodPrice1);
                p = getFoodItem(p, c[lineNumber].foodName2, sizeof(c[lineNumber].foodName2), &c[lineNumber].foodPrice2);
                p = getFoodItem(p, c[lineNumber].foodName3, sizeof(c[lineNumber].foodName3), &c[lineNumber].foodPrice3);
                printf("---%s---\n", c[lineNumber].foodCategory);
                printf("%s\t%lf\n", c[lineNumber].foodName1, c[lineNumber].foodPrice1);
                printf("%s\t%lf\n", c[lineNumber].foodName2, c[lineNumber].foodPrice2);
                printf("%s\t%lf\n", c[lineNumber].foodName3, c[lineNumber].foodPrice3);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                index++;
            }
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No file found");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    print_food();
}
```